# On Ubuntu 19.10, eoan, how to install sqlite3 package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

Given the normal install on eoan, I'm failing to install sqlite3. What gives?

```
  $ apt -u install sqlite3
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.29.0-2) but 3.29.0-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: "impossible situation" is the key. Show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                       
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Comment: You don't seem to have an eoan-security pocket. Add it. Optionally, also add eoan-updates. Your incomplete sources are the cause of your problem: Version 3.29.0-2ubuntu0.1 is in eoan-security and eoan-updates, so you either had those sources in the past, or you manually downloaded the wrong package.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I did not have all the needed eoan repos:

Edit the /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
  $ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add the following lines at the end:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
```

Save and quit. Then upgrade:

```
  $ sudo apt update
  $ sudo apt -u dist-upgrade
```